# How to pass arguments to Perl one liner?

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $a;
$a=qx(date --date "+3 min" '+ %Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S');
system( q(perl -pi.back -e 's{/2013/07/31-05:54:14/}{$a}g;' /tmp/ron/replace.txt));
```

I'm getting the date from server adding 3mins to it and assigining it to $a variable, but i'm not able to print that using the one liner. How to print a variable in perl one liner?

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing this in bash, then it's probably simpler to replace your entire operation with the following `sed` command:

```
sed 's!/2013/07/31-05:54:14/!'"$(date --date "+3 min" '+ %Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S')"'!g'
```

This will insert the output of the `date` command into the `sed` substitution string.

Also, I see that you've got a `/` character at the start and end of your search string.  Did you mean to include those as part of the search string?

In your original command, you need to interpolate `$a` into the `system` command which you could do like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $a;
$a = qx(date --date "+3 min" '+ %Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S');
system( q(perl -pi.back -e 's{/2013/07/31-05:54:14/}{) . $a . q(}g;' /tmp/ron/replace.txt));
```

The `$a` does not expand inside a `q()` string (which is equivalent to a string surrounded by `'`) so I've closed the `q()` and concatenated `$a` the reopened `q()`.

Calling perl from within a perl script is a little clunky. Essentially, you're just wanting to use the output of the date command in a one-liner, so something like this might also be simpler:

```
bash$ perl -pi.back -e 's{/2013/07/31-05:54:14/}{'"$(date --date "+3 min" '+ %Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S')"' /tmp/ron/replace.txt
```

Although this is pretty similar to using `sed`.